# New ffmpeg build will not concat, gives no error message

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, bug

At the risk of this being a bug, and not something I'm doing wrong, I'm posting here mostly because I don't even know where to report ffmpeg bugs.

It looks like the newest version of ffmpeg `ffmpeg version 2023-12-21-git-1e42a48e37-full_build-www.gyan.dev` will not run the concat filter correctly, when used in combination with vstack. I don't think these two very common filters would be changed syntactically in only the one year since I last upgraded my ffmpeg, but if this is something I'm doing wrong, please tell me.

I have the following ffmpeg command, running through a batch script in Windows CMD:

```
rem Folder and file paths
set speakerPath=C:\
set slidesPath=C:\
set outputPath=C:\

rem -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set commands=-crf 24 -c:a aac -b:a 96k -ac 1 -movflags +faststart 
ffmpeg -ss 00:53:11.124 -t 00:00:53.720 -i %speakerPath%speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 01:40:03.403 -t 00:08:05.819 -i %speakerPath%speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 01:48:49.229 -t 00:04:32.372 -i %speakerPath%speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 01:54:22.229 -t 00:02:46.834 -i %speakerPath%speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 00:53:11.091 -t 00:00:53.720 -i %slidesPath%slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 01:40:03.370 -t 00:08:05.819 -i %slidesPath%slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 01:48:49.196 -t 00:04:32.372 -i %slidesPath%slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 -ss 01:54:22.196 -t 00:02:46.834 -i %slidesPath%slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4 \
   -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[speakerv][speakera]; \
                    [4][5][6][7]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[slides]; \
                    [speakerv][slides]vstack=inputs=2[v1],[v1]scale=-1:1080[v2]" \
                    -map "[v2]" -map "[speakera]" %commands% %outputPath%output.mp4
```

You can see that it takes several inputs with in/out times, concats them, then vertically stacks them. The command does exactly what it is supposed to do with `ffmpeg version 2022-03-07-git-e645a1ddb9-full_build-www.gyan.dev`.

However, when I upgraded to the most recent build `ffmpeg version 2023-12-21-git-1e42a48e37-full_build-www.gyan.dev`, the command will not run correctly. It runs without any errors, but it runs as if the concat filters are not even being considered. It skips straight to the vstack filter and outputs the vstack correctly, but only with the first input.

Here are the LOGS. You can see the issue when it reports output video time as `time=00:00:53.52`, when it should be `time=00:16:18.81`. I don't see any errors or warnings. It's almost like it is running without the concat filters at all, jumping straight to the vstack with the first inputs from the concat filter.

```
ffmpeg version 2023-12-21-git-1e42a48e37-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 36.100 / 58. 36.100
  libavcodec     60. 36.100 / 60. 36.100
  libavformat    60. 20.100 / 60. 20.100
  libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavfilter     9. 14.100 /  9. 14.100
  libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
  libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
  libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #1:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #2:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #2:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #3:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #3:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #4:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #4:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #5:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #5:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #6:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #6:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #7:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #7:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : SoundHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #3:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #5:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #6:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #7:0 (h264) -> concat
  scale:default -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] profile High, level 3.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] 264 - core 164 r3172 c1c9931 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2023 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=24.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    encoder         : Lavf60.20.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 960x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 11988 tbn
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc60.36.100 libx264
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc60.36.100 aac
[mp4 @ 000001e1fc0fbf40] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file0 speed=2.35x
[out#0/mp4 @ 000001e1fdcc1c80] video:2169kB audio:662kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.081158%
frame= 1606 fps= 72 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2891kB time=00:00:53.52 bitrate= 442.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1600 speed=2.39x
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] frame I:7     Avg QP:18.49  size: 42064
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] frame P:405   Avg QP:18.76  size:  2688
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] frame B:1194  Avg QP:25.40  size:   702
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.0%  0.0% 99.1%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] mb I  I16..4: 28.8% 51.3% 19.9%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  0.9%  0.2%  P16..4: 11.5%  1.8%  1.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:83.6%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 11.9%  0.3%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:87.7%  L0:42.2% L1:57.0% BI: 0.8%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] 8x8 transform intra:50.8% inter:87.8%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 31.4% 50.0% 22.6% inter: 1.2% 2.1% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] i16 v,h,dc,p: 60% 24%  6% 10%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 16% 47%  3%  2%  3%  2%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 49% 21% 11%  3%  3%  4%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 21% 22%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.2% UV:0.7%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] ref P L0: 67.3% 10.8% 15.8%  6.0%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] ref B L0: 88.1% 10.0%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] ref B L1: 95.9%  4.1%
[libx264 @ 000001e18c448080] kb/s:331.54
[aac @ 000001e18c44b480] Qavg: 302.654
```

```
ffmpeg version 2022-03-07-git-e645a1ddb9-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavcodec     59. 22.100 / 59. 22.100
  libavformat    59. 17.103 / 59. 17.103
  libavdevice    59.  5.100 / 59.  5.100
  libavfilter     8. 27.100 /  8. 27.100
  libswscale      6.  5.100 /  6.  5.100
  libswresample   4.  4.100 /  4.  4.100
  libpostproc    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #1:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #1:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #2:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #2:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\speaker_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
  Duration: 02:19:25.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25178 kb/s
  Stream #3:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24998 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : AVC Coding
  Stream #3:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-25T14:59:21.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #4:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #4:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #5:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #5:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #6:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #6:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\slides_2019-04-25_09-59-21.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
  Duration: 02:19:26.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1288 kb/s
  Stream #7:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1104 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #7:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 176 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #3:1 (aac) -> concat
  Stream #4:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #5:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #6:0 (h264) -> concat
  Stream #7:0 (h264) -> concat
  scale:default -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] profile High, level 3.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] 264 - core 164 r3094 bfc87b7 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=24.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.103
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 960x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:9], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 11988 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.22.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.22.100 aac
[mp4 @ 0000020f9ab7bf80] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file18 speed=2.38x
frame=29338 fps= 71 q=-1.0 Lsize=   46001kB time=00:16:18.81 bitrate= 385.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=29329 speed=2.38x
video:33194kB audio:11755kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.342363%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] frame I:120   Avg QP:17.97  size: 69944
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] frame P:7394  Avg QP:20.84  size:  2127
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] frame B:21824 Avg QP:25.37  size:   452
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.1% 99.1%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] mb I  I16..4: 31.7% 41.9% 26.5%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  0.5%  0.1%  P16..4:  8.4%  1.7%  1.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:87.9%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  8.5%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:91.3%  L0:41.5% L1:57.9% BI: 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] 8x8 transform intra:48.0% inter:82.4%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 35.5% 55.7% 32.7% inter: 0.7% 1.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] i16 v,h,dc,p: 67% 16%  8%  9%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 15% 47%  4%  3%  4%  3%  3%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 44% 20% 11%  4%  4%  5%  4%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 58% 19% 20%  4%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.3%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] ref P L0: 66.7% 11.1% 16.0%  6.0%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] ref B L0: 87.5% 10.6%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] ref B L1: 96.4%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 0000020f9a3fba80] kb/s:277.78
[aac @ 0000020f9a3fca40] Qavg: 2402.612
```